# Django Query ManyToMany with Custom Through Table Field Data

Tags: django, model, many-to-many

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now but am confused. Every `ManyToMany` relationship always goes through a third table which isn't that difficult to understand. But in the event that the third table is a custom through table with additional fields how do you grab the custom field for each row?

Here's a sample table I made. How can I get all the movies a User has watched along with the additional `watched` field and `finished` field? **This example assumes the user is only allowed to see the movie once whether they finish it or not so there will only be 1 record for each movie they saw.**

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=191)

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=191)
    watched = models.ManyToMany(Movie, through='watch')

class Watch(models.Model):
    user = models.Foreignkey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.Foreignkey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    watched = models.DateTimeField()
    finished = models.BooleanField()
```

Penny for your thoughts my friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can uses:

```
from django.db.models import F

my_user.watched.annotate(
    watched=F('watch__watched'),
    finished=F('watch__finished')
)
```

This will return a `QuerySet` of `Movie`s that contain as extra attributes `.watched` and `.finished`.

That being said, it might be cleaner to just access the `watch_set`, and thus iterate over the `Watch` objects and access the `.movie` object for details about the movie. You can use [**`.select_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to fetch the information about the `Movie`s in the *same* database query:

```
for watch in my_user.watch_set.select_related('movie'):
    print(f'{watch.movie.title}: {watch.watched}, {watch.finished}')
```